# Angular JSON Filter for Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using $http to fetch a collection of users. The raw response from the server is this...

```
[{"id":2,"name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@infosnap.com"}]
```

Logging the data parameter in the success callback shows this...

```
[Object, each: function, eachSlice: function, all: function, any: function, collect: function…]
  0: Object
    $$hashKey: "004"
    email: "johndoe@infosnap.com"
    id: 2
    name: "John Doe"
    __proto__: Object
  length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Good enough. Looks like $http already de-serialized the raw JSON into a JavaScript object.

Next, I assign the data to a $scope variable, inside the success callback, in order to perform some debugging in the browser...

```
$scope.debug = data;
```

Now, in my view, I want to display this as pretty JSON in order to debug.

```
<pre>{{debug | json}}</pre>
```

And I get this...

```
"[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"johndoe@infosnap.com\", \"$$hashKey\": \"004\"}]"
```

I am trying to get something like this...

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@infosnap.com",
    "$$hashKey": "004"
  }
]
```

I also tried to stringify the javascript array in the controller...

```
$scope.debug = JSON.stringify(data, true);
```

and not use the filter...

```
<pre>{{debug}}</pre>
```

but I get the same results, except the $$hashKey has been removed...

```
"[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"johndoe@infosnap.com\"}]"
```

If I just assign the first item in the array to $scope, and use the json filter, it works fine...

```
$scope.debug = data[0];
```

In my view...

```
<pre>{{debug | json}}</pre>
```

Results in...

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@infosnap.com"
}
```

I know there are other ways to get what I want. I am just trying to understand what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use the console?  O.o

Comment: Thanks. I am using the console, and that works fine. But, I would like to get to the bottom of the issue rather than just working around it. I want to understand why it does not work as I would expect. Either it is working correctly, and I misunderstand how it is supposed to work, or I understand correctly how it is supposed to work, but I am doing it slightly wrong, or I understand how it is supposed to work, and am doing it correctly, but there is some bug in the filter code. Just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the json instead of stringify.

Try this:

`$scope.debug = JSON.parse(data)`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/582/)

Comment: Thanks Beteraraba, I tried that, but the issue is that within the success callback for the $http get call, the json has already been parsed into a JavaScript array object.